# Stop code after if statement from executing when error occurs

Tags: php

This is what my code looks like:

```
if($allthevaluesarenotempty) {
    if($pictureexist) {
        // upload picture code
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "error";
    }

    // sql query here
}
```

How can I stop the SQL query from executing when `$message` is set?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You have wrong stated your goal - you should not stop if message occurs, but you should show message when you stop.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe I tried to redirect the page when an error occurs  `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); ` but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Put the `// sql query here` after `// upload picture code`?

Comment: @minitech but I want to excute it if there is no image!

Comment: @shnisaka: Your question says specifically that you want to stop the query from executing when `$message` is set. If you actually meant the opposite of that, put it in the `else` instead.

Comment: write functions. that often helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If in case of loops like while, for and foreach, you can use `continue;` to escape the iteration and `break;` to end the loop.
- In function `return false;` will stop the execution.
- In a PHP document, `exit()` will terminate further execution of the script.

So, use which is suitable.

Comment: what about `return true;` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

check `$message` to see if there was an error:

```
if($allthevaluesarenotempty) {

    $message = '';     

    if ($pictureexist) {

        // upload picture code

    } else {

        $message = "error";

    } // if $pictureexist

} // if $allyourvalues...

// later in your code check $message

if ($message == 'error') {

   // do something, there was an error...

} // if $message
```

Comment: `if ($message == 'error')` may return `warning` or notice if `$allthevaluesarenotempty` is false.

Answer (score 1):

you could check variable `$message` and see if it is euql to "error":

```
if($allthevaluesarenotempty) {
    if($pictureexist){
       // upload picture code
    }
    else
    {
       $message = "error";
    }
    if (@$message != "error")) { 
       //sql query here
    }
 }
```

or you can put your sql query in the `if` block

```
 if($allthevaluesarenotempty) {
    if($pictureexist){
       // upload picture code

       //sql query here
    }
    else
    {
       $message = "error";
    }
 }
```